# Need explanation how we got right hand side of expression from the left hand side

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need explanation how we got the right hand side of expression from the left hand side. I do not understand algebra behind this conversion...
[image]
Thanks for help

Comment: Multiply the denominator & the numerator by $$\prod_{t=1}^{n-r}t=(n-r)!$$

Comment: @PutinHuylo Do you understand what $n!$ means?

Comment: $\large \frac{n(n-1)...(n-(r-1))}{r!}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-(r-1))}{r!}.\frac{(n-r)!}{(n-r)!}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To win the jackpot in Lotto 6/49, a lottery in Canada similar to Mega Bucks (except that there is no Mega Ball), you need to match the 6 winning numbers drawn from the set of 49 balls numbered from 1 to 49. There is a bonus ball drawn, but it isn't applicable to the jackpot prize.

It may be useful to understanding the answer to your question by using a numerical example, so let's find the number of possible combinations of Lotto 6/49 tickets.

The number of combinations is
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{49\cdot48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6}&(1)
\end{array}$$

Notice how the numerator is a descending product, but that it doesn't descend all the way to 1. Now we're going to make it descend all the way.
$$\frac{49\cdot48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6}\cdot\color{green}{\frac{43\cdot42\cdot43\dots3\cdot2\cdot1}{43\cdot42\cdot43\dots3\cdot2\cdot1}}$$
Restating in factorial form we have
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{49!}{6!43!}&(2)
\end{array}$$
Equating, (1) and (2), we have

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{49\cdot48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6}=\frac{49!}{6!43!}&(3)
\end{array}$$

Noting that $43=49-6$ and that $44=49-6+1$ we have
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{49\cdot(49-1)\cdot(49-2)\cdot46\cdot45\cdot(49-6+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6}=\frac{49!}{6!(49-6)!}&(4)
\end{array}$$
Finally we can generalize this formula by noting that $n=49$ and that $r=6$
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\dots(n-r+1)}{r!}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}&(5)
\end{array}$$

By the way, the odds of winning the 6/49 jackpot are about $14,000,000:1$.

The odds of being struck by lighting, twice, is about $9,000,000:1$.

Answer (score 2):

n! is defined as n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 1 for n in N. If we would divide n! by (n-r)!, we could cancel (n-r) * (n-r-1) * ... * 1 from the quotient. So all thats happened is that both numerator and denominator are multiplied by (n-r)!. The right hand side is then the common definition of nCr.